# Self employed minor's tax?

Tags: taxes, usa

My son is a beginner voice actor. He is 14, a dependent child. When he starts to make money, when and how does he file taxes? Does he file separately or with us(parents). I have read that minors begin to pay tax after the income is $6,300, but self employed people pay after $400.

How does this pertain to him? At what threshold does he begin? Does he file with the parents or separately? Thanks!

We are in Mississippi, I have not done any state specific research.

Comment: Hi Niamke, welcome to Freelancing.SE! We can't answer any tax questions without knowing where you are. Please [edit] your question to include your location in the question, as well as a tag. This will help people answer your question with accuracy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started freelancing when I was 16 and I'm in NH, USA.

At the end of my first year (which was 4-6 months) I payed taxes on my own and not on my parents return. I believe I made around $5,000 in those few months.

The IRS has a system to [determine if you need to file taxes](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Do-I-Need-to-File-a-Tax-Return%3F). I have not tried this but I'm sure it's useful.

Comment: I did the test, it said that yes, he had to file taxes because, even though he's a minor, he met the $400 self employment tax bracket. It says he will have to report it on a 1040-C and 1040-SE, but can probably put it on our(parents') return. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful. Please also note that he will NOT have income withheld from his income and he will owe 20-30% at the end of the year. I recommend putting 20-25% of all earnings in a separate bank account just for your sons self-employment taxes.

Answer (score 0):

I am no tax expert, nor am I an American but...

I suspect the $6,300 figure you quote for minors relates to income derived from non-employment (cash gifts or income from savings trusts). In most (all?) western countries, minimum age age for working is 16 years old, and the number of hours that can be worked at a young age is also limited. Anything else would be a breach of employment laws, possible child cruelty. I would call your local tax office and ask them for advice. The risk/penalty for getting this wrong could lead to child services getting involved despite your best intentions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in northern MS, and the nearest office is in Jackson, MS I believe. As for the $6,300, it was for employment(such as a summer job at a fast food restaurant.)